# Service account becomes inactive in windows 2008 application server

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a service account in windows 2008 application server to achieve word to pdf conversion. 3-4 days back everything was working fine and all of a sudden the functionality shut down.

I dig into details. The information I got is as below:

1. When I log in with that service account and try to achieve that functionality, I'm able to do it.
2. When I log off with service account and try to achieve that functionality, I'm not able to do it.

Conclusion: Somehow the service account gets inactive.

The problem is very weird and i tried each and every combination of permission in Dcom config. Any help in right direction is highly appreciated. Thank a ton in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You already tried to check the Password Never Expires and User Cannot Change The Password options in Active Directory Users and Computers?
Also, try to re-install the application on the machine. If the application cannot run as Windows Service, use the SRVANY.EXE utility to register you application.